# Does Mandrill have a limit on Email size or POST size through API?

Tags: email, post, limit, mandrill, filemaker

The scenario: HTML emails are getting delivered successfully through Mandrill but the content looks as though it's cut off half-way through the email. Mandrill is giving me a JSON success message when I hit the API using POST method.

Because the HTML is cut-off halfway through the email it makes me think there is either a character limit for the email Body/Message when POSTing or there is a limit in Mandrill on the Body/Message size of the email.

**My question is; is there any known limit on either POSTing to the Mandrill API or on the Email size sent through Mandrill? Or any other suspected reason for this happening?**

*(The account Mandrill is in test mode at the moment, I am also using FileMaker's [Insert from URL] method to POST - in case this information is relevant.)*

Comment: There are no size limit that I am aware of or have been subjected to when using Mandrill. Have you tried using different content in the emails. Is the content cut off at the same place all the time in the emails? It can also be the case that the html of the content is broken so that your email client is cutting the content where the error is (not closed html tags etc.) Web browsers are generally more tolerant to html errors than email clients.

Answer (score 2):

From Mandrill Knowledge Base:

> Messages in Mandrill can't exceed 25MB in total size (including
> content and attachments). There is no specific limit for individual
> attachments, just the total size of the message. Because attachments
> are Base64-encoded, this generally means that they will be 1/3 larger
> when sending than they are on disk due to the encoding.

https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038804694